# How to get a Handle of the Navbar from a view controller inside a container view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, ioc-container, parentviewcontroller

I have a container view embedded in a view controller. The container is used to display different view controllers. How can I change the title or add a button to the navigation bar in the parent?

Thanks!

Comment: Ended up using notification center to update the title. The sent when the child view is called.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the navigationItem that controls those attributes directly as so (assuming self = your childViewController:

```
[self.parentViewController.navigationItem setTitle:<Your Text>];
[self.parentViewController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:<Your Button>];
```

Comment: You're calling 'self' from the childViewController, right? If so, NSLog(@"%@", self.parentViewController) and see what it's returning. I may not be understanding your viewController hierarchy correctly.

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", self.parentViewController) returns null

Comment: How are you adding these views to your parentViewController? If you do this programmatically like, [mainViewController addChildViewController:self.childViewController];, then self.childViewController.parentViewController will return mainViewController

Comment: [fromViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [self addChildViewController:toViewController];
    
    [self transitionFromViewController:fromViewController toViewController:toViewController duration:0.45 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:nil completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        
        [fromViewController removeFromParentViewController];
        [toViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
        self.transitionInProgress = NO;
    }];

Comment: Haha, Yeah it is. Could you add those lines as an edit to your original post?